# Comparando os dados

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como comparar vários elementos, nesse exemplo tenho apenas quatro. Mas na listagem tenho mais de 40. Se fosse fazer um a um, o código ficaria incompreensivo e passível de grandes erros... Alguém pode me ajudar como fazer uma comparação com várias variáveis? Desde já agradeço sua ajuda!

```
$result1 = $result['linha'][0]['elemento'][0]['tempo']['text'];
$result2 = $result['linha'][0]['elemento'][1]['tempo']['text'];
$result3 = $result['linha'][0]['elemento'][2]['tempo']['text'];
$result4 = $result['linha'][0]['elemento'][3]['tempo']['text'];

$endereço1 = "rua alves fiho";

if ($result1 < $result2) {
    $result1 = $endereço1;
}
```

Comment: No título você fala em comparação, depois fala em ordenação, depois fala de fazer código manualmente, coisas que são diferentes. Seria legal você clicar em [edit] e complementar sua postagem explicando melhor qual é a sua dúvida exatamente (qual o problema que está tendo de fato, e não apenas como está tentando solucionar), pra que possamos ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar arrays você pode usar a função [sort()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php)